# com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException Insert mysql error

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

This is the whole message I receive:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''user','age','school','password') values ('Admin','22','tei','admin')' at line 1

And this is the code:

```
String user = textField.getText().trim();
String age = textField_3.getText().trim();
String school = textField_4.getText().trim();
String password = String.valueOf(passwordField.getPassword());
String password1 = String.valueOf(passwordField_1.getPassword());

if(password.equals(password1)){


Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/users","root","1234");
PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement("insert into user ('user','age','school','password') values ('"+user+"','"+age+"','"+school+"','"+password+"')");
int rs = st.executeUpdate();

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Data Saved Successfully");
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The point of prepared statements is, among others, to not concatenate your queries yourself.

You want to do the following:

```
//first you "prepare" your statement (where the '?' acts as a kind of placeholder)
PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement("insert into user (user,age,school,password) values (?,?,?,?);");
//now you bind the data to your parameters
st.setString(1, user);
...
//and then you can execute it
st.executeUpdate()
```

For more details see [the official tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html).

There are a couple of things happening behind the scenes that make the query safe, like escaping special characters that would otherwise allow altering the statement (google SQL injections if you want to know more)

Comment: I get the same message again! :/

Comment: try to remove the ' from your column names, does that help?

Comment: you are forgetting the semicolon at the end of the statement.

Comment: Now I am getting another error:
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'user' in 'field list'

Comment: well, is there a column named user in the user table?

Comment: @jmsalcido I am getting the same error from the beginning
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''user','age','school','password') values ('Admin','22','TEI Peiraia','admin')' at line 1

Comment: @k-mera yes all the columns in the tables are named the same as the query

Comment: replace insert into user (user,age,school,password) for insert into user ('user','age','school','password') and dont forget the semicolon...

Comment: I found it! 
     Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/users","root","1234");
     PreparedStatement st = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO user (username,age,school,password) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
     st.setString(1, user);
     st.setString(2, age);
     st.setString(3, school);
     st.setString(4, password);
     st.executeUpdate();
     st.close();
     con.close();