# How to insert sql query in java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I connected the sql server to intellij idea. I want to execute the inserting query (the code is written below). But with the following code , I'm not able to insert data into the database. I am creating address book n java using intellij idea and MySQL server and taking input from user with insert query:

```
B.addActionListener( new ActionListener( ) {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    try
    {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        DriverManager.registerDriver( DriverManager.getDriver( "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql" ) );

        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql", "root", "root");

        Statement st = con.createStatement();
       String rs = "insert into mysql57.addressbook" +"(fname,lname,addr,phonenum,id,email)" +"values(?,?,?,?,?,?)";

        System.out.println(532 );
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(rs);
        preparedStatement.setString(1, TUID.getText());
        preparedStatement.setString(2, tfn.getText());
        preparedStatement.setString(3, tln.getText());
        preparedStatement.setString(4, tpn.getText());
        preparedStatement.setString(5, tad.getText());
        preparedStatement.setString(6, tmail.getText());
        System.out.println(88 );
      preparedStatement.executeUpdate(rs);
      }
    catch (Exception ex){}
```

Comment: Please log the exception caught and analyze/post what is the exact exception you are receiving

Comment: there is no exception, the code compiles and runs fine but the issue is that the entry doesn't get inserted in db

There is only one warning "Wed Nov 15 15:41:34 IST 2017 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended."

Comment: try to close the statement and connect and then check the database. also use commit .

Comment: sorry, my catch block was empty, exception is - "com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?,?,?,?,?,?)' at line 1
"

Comment: You are using the wrong `executeUpdate` method, you need to use the one **without** parameters. See the duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

```
B.addActionListener( new ActionListener( ) {
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
try
{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
    DriverManager.registerDriver( DriverManager.getDriver( "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql" ) );

    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql", "root", "root");

    Statement st = con.createStatement();
   String rs = "insert into mysql57.addressbook" +"(fname,lname,addr,phonenum,id,email)" +"values(?,?,?,?,?,?)";

    System.out.println(532 );
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(rs);
    preparedStatement.setString(1, TUID.getText());
    preparedStatement.setString(2, tfn.getText());
    preparedStatement.setString(3, tln.getText());
    preparedStatement.setString(4, tpn.getText());
    preparedStatement.setString(5, tad.getText());
    preparedStatement.setString(6, tmail.getText());
    System.out.println(88 );
  preparedStatement.executeUpdate(rs);
  }
catch (Exception ex){
//Any exception caught will be logged here. 
ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Your catch block is empty, probably there is an exception but its being swallowed.

Comment: sorry, my catch block was empty, exception is - "com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?,?,?,?,?,?)' at line 1 "

Comment: Try to dont concatenate the query yourself. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21207049/com-mysql-jdbc-exceptions-jdbc4-mysqlsyntaxerrorexception-insert-mysql-error. 
And close the connection after execute update line.